# how can you key frame the entire scene at once?

Tags: keyframes

what im trying to get:
press 1 button
everything that can be key framed is key framed
like in sfm you can select everything and key frame everything at once

any way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like an overkill. Maybe you should tell us what you really wanna do? What’s your end target?

Comment: what kind of keyframe? You can just press I on your keyboard and select keyframe you want but I am not sure what do you want same as @Chris

Comment: I think you might rather want to create a whole new linked scene and tweak the parameters there. Keyframing is notorious for hurting performance and it's not really well suited for such an overkill use :)